Error URI malformed when running Remix application
I am trying to run Remix app locally.
When running npm run dev I get the following error:
12:53:02 PM [vite] Internal server error: URI malformed
      at decodeURI (<anonymous>)
      at viteTransformMiddleware (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:63657:19)
      at call (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42944:7)
      at next (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42888:5)
      at viteServePublicMiddleware (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:53542:20)
      at call (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42944:7)
      at next (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42888:5)
      at viteHMRPingMiddleware (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:65046:13)
      at call (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42944:7)
      at next (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42888:5)
      at next (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42866:14)
      at viteCachedTransformMiddleware (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:63642:9)
      at call (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42944:7)
      at next (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42888:5)
      at cors (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:43416:7)
      at file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:43452:17
      at originCallback (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:43442:15)
      at file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:43447:13
      at optionsCallback (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:43427:9)
      at corsMiddleware (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:43432:7)
      at call (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42944:7)
      at next (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42888:5)
      at Function.handle (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42891:3)
      at Server.app (file:///C:/Users/anted/Documents/GitHub/remix-strapi-contacts-app/remix-contacts-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:42756:37)
      at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1072:12)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)

I checked the suggested solution here but I don't have a "public/index.html" file from where to remove "%PUBLIC_URL%"
Do you have any suggestions how can I fix hits issue? Thanks in advance!

That's hard to say. What was the URL? Was there anything before this error message? Did the error occur when you started your app, or did you click a link/post a form, etc? Basically, what were you doing when the error occurred?

I just open http://localhost:5173/ and I get the issue without even interacting with the page

Yeah, something seems really odd. Does the basic create-remix app work? Is the repo you're working on public?

Yes, the repo is public, here it is https://github.com/teodorazhelyazkova/remix-contacts-app I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yIivwrvH6w&t=3683s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org which actually follows the tutorial from the Remix docs but also adds Strapi https://remix.run/docs/en/main/start/tutorial

The repo you have requires strapi to be running. Have you gone through the get started guide on strapi.io? I setup strapi, create a new content type for the contacts, added an API key, added to .env file, then updated the fetch calls to pass Authorization: Bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN}. After all that, everything works fine... I'm not sure what the tutorial had, but it looks like you're missing a bunch of steps. I created a PR to your repo with more instructions https://github.com/teodorazhelyazkova/remix-contacts-app/pull/1

Yes, but I haven't generated the API key before. I did it now and I still get the same error. I've replied with screenshots in your PR as well. Also, I didn't mention it before but thank you for the time you spent on this issue and for all of the help!

The issue was caused by how the css was imported with Vite. Here is the fix from Michael https://github.com/teodorazhelyazkova/remix-contacts-app/pull/2 @Kiliman thanks again for the help!
